# How to update MySQL Table with Puppet?

Tags: mysql, puppet

I want to update the values in a MySQL table using Puppet.

Basically I want to run something like this:

```
update Servers set ipPrivate="10.1.2.3" where hostName="x.example.com";
```

`ipPrivate` and `hostName` will be in storeconfigs, and will have quite a few different combinations of values.

I could just do this with `exec`, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the idea of using a plain exec, you can always wrap it up as a [defined type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html), i.e.

```
define mysqlupdate (params) {
    exec { "update-sql-${name}":
        ...
    }
}
```

Defined types let you easily reuse the code too.